# Apache spark : best way to join 2 hive tables

Tags: apache-spark, hive

what is the best way to join 2 hive tables (external), with spark,  in terms of performance ?

a) with spark sql

`spark.sql("select * from tableA join tableB on a=b)`

b) reading parquet files directly

```
val df1 = spark.read.parquet("/hdfs/location1")
val df2 = spark.read.parquet("/hdfs/location2")
val joined = df1.join(df2, Seq("id"), "inner")
```

are there any difference ? would it be a difference if the tables were managed ?

I noticed that the plans are the same but joining the tables from hive it is always downloading on the executors the whole file size.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, rather it depends on a developer's comfort on selecting either Spark SQL or DataFrame, he/she wants to use. It really does not matter in terms of performance, since the underlying spark built-ins functions mirrors each other ( DataFrame and Spark-SQL ).

A while ago, when I had this thought, I was going through blog by Confessions of Data guy - [dataframes-vs-sparksql](https://www.confessionsofadataguy.com/dataframes-vs-sparksql-which-one-should-you-choose/)

He mentions in the last section of the blog,

> I think the difference between SparkSQL and DataFrames in pipelines is probably more theoretical and emotional than anything else.

I definitely agree with these sentences.